# Does compiler optimize away intermediaries

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

I am trying to optimize an exaggerated version of the following code.

```
int a = startvalue1;
int b = startvalue2;
int c = startvalue3;

int ta = a + b;
int tb = b + c;
int tc = c + a;

int tta = ta * tb;
int ttb = tb * tc;
int ttc = tc * ta;

int finalvalue1 = tta - ttc;
int finalvalue2 = ttb - ttc;
int finalvalue3 = ttc + tta;
```

Will the compiler automatically get rid of the intermediaries?  If not, will my code run faster if I get rid of them?

I have profiled my program and I have to optimize my discrete fourier transform.  But getting rid of the intermediaries would be tedious and I'd like to avoid it if the compiler is going to do it for me.

Comment: Of course.  The only thing you can do wrong is not checking this for yourself, look at the disassembly.

Comment: Generally the way to see what the optimizer is doing with your code is to look at the generated assembly.

Comment: The problem is that there is no clear-cut yes or no answer. It depends on the compiler, the compiler options, the surrounding code, etc... The only way to know for sure is to look at the assembly.

Comment: If you want to be certain that your code compiled in your environment is optimized a particular way then you need to do that research.  A general answer may or may not be correct, especially since you've only shown a snippet of code and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the disassembly output for your compiler while compiling with optimizations on.

If you use Visual Studio, set a break-point and press ctrl+f11.
If you use gcc, use the -S flag to output the assembly.

On my system, Visual Studio 2012 removes all of the intermediate steps.

Here is the test program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
    int startvalue1 = 10 ;
    int startvalue2 = 15 ;
    int startvalue3 = 20 ;

    int a = startvalue1;
    int b = startvalue2;
    int c = startvalue3;

    int ta = a + b;
    int tb = b + c;
    int tc = c + a;

    int tta = ta * tb;
    int ttb = tb * tc;
    int ttc = tc * ta;

    int finalvalue1 = tta - ttc;
    int finalvalue2 = ttb - ttc;
    int finalvalue3 = ttc + tta;

    // This line is only here make sure everything isn't optimized out!
    std::cout << finalvalue1 << finalvalue2 << finalvalue3 ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Here is the optimized assembly:

```
01291270 8B 0D 30 30 29 01    mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[1293030h]  
01291276 68 59 06 00 00       push        659h  
0129127B 68 2C 01 00 00       push        12Ch  
01291280 6A 7D                push        7Dh  
01291282 FF 15 38 30 29 01    call        dword ptr ds:[1293038h]  
01291288 8B C8                mov         ecx,eax  
0129128A FF 15 38 30 29 01    call        dword ptr ds:[1293038h]  
01291290 8B C8                mov         ecx,eax  
01291292 FF 15 38 30 29 01    call        dword ptr ds:[1293038h]
01291298 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
0129129A C3                   ret
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void)
{
    std::cout << 125 << 300 << 1625 ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks.  SO wow, it optimized everything away.  THanks for the assembly tips.

Comment: @deanresin Many people underestimate the power of compiler optimizations. Just remember, compilers are generally written by very smart people.

Comment: The code might look different if you were not using constants for the values.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's a good point. I'll leave checking the disassembly of using external functions as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: @jliv902 turns out your answer was pretty useless considering the constants lol.  thanks for trying.  I looked at the assembly and I can see the intermediary variable names in it so I assume that means at least some of the intermediaries were not compiled away.

Comment: @deanresin It depends on your compiler. My disassembly shows all of the source code, including the intermediate variables, even though they are optimized out. You have to look at the assembly instructions themselves. This also doesn't make my answer useless since you looked at the assembly after all. I just wrote a function that gets an integer from the user. The compiler now has to perform the intermediate calculations, but it still optimizes the intermediate variables out.